# Find last column with data and add data after that column

Tags: excel

I have some data in my worksheet and what I want to achieve is that I want to add data after 1 column from the last column with data. 
I have tried the `Range().End` property but I think I am not able to implement it correctly.

```
colnum = Sheet3.Range("A:Z").End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
```

The above code gives me the column number as '1' and plus 2 means it gives column number '3' which is 'C'.
Data in my worksheet is something like this:

[image]
I want a dynamic search and my code should find column 'E' as the last column with data and start adding data from column 'F'. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns an array where the first element is the last row number, and the second element the last column number.

```
Function LastRowCol(Worksht) As Long()
'Uncomment if on worksheet
'Application.Volatile
    Dim WS As Worksheet, R As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim L(1) As Long

Select Case TypeName(Worksht)
    Case "String"
        Set WS = Worksheets(Worksht)
    Case "Worksheet"
        Set WS = Worksht
End Select

With WS
    Set R = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                    searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

    If Not R Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = R.Row
        LastCol = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
                    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Else
        LastRow = 1
        LastCol = 1
    End If
End With

L(0) = LastRow
L(1) = LastCol
LastRowCol = L
End Function

Sub change_code_name()
'Requires Trust Access to VBA Object Model

  Dim wbk As Object, sheet As Object
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.name = "VBAProject"
Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveWorkbook.CodeName)
  wbk.name = "wbk_code_name"
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).CodeName)
  sheet.name = "sheet_code_name"
End Sub
```

In the case of your code line, assuming your worksheet CodeName is `Sheet3`, it would be something like:

```
colnum = LastRowCol(Sheet3)(1) + 1
```

and would apply to the active workbook.

See also [Error in finding last used cell in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) for an extensive discussion of the various methods of finding the last row/column and the pitfalls of each.

**Edit:**

Examining your screenshot, it seems that you might want to exclude Row 1 from the testing.  If that is the case, then try this slightly modified code:

```
Option Explicit
Function LastRowCol(Worksht, Optional excludeRows As Long = 0) As Long()
'Uncomment if on worksheet
'Application.Volatile
    Dim WS As Worksheet, R As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim L(1) As Long
    Dim searchRng As Range

Select Case TypeName(Worksht)
    Case "String"
        Set WS = Worksheets(Worksht)
    Case "Worksheet"
        Set WS = Worksht
End Select

If excludeRows > 0 Then
    With WS
        Set searchRng = Range(.Cells(excludeRows + 1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count))
    End With
Else
    Set searchRng = WS.Cells
End If

With searchRng
    Set R = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                    searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

    If Not R Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = R.Row
        LastCol = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
                    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Else
        LastRow = 1
        LastCol = 1
    End If
End With

L(0) = excludeRows + 1
L(1) = LastCol
LastRowCol = L
End Function
```

and, in your macro:

```
colnum = LastRowCol(Sheet3,1)(1) + 1
```